# Could anyone explain clearly how to compute the advantage function in reinforcement learning?

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I have troubles understanding how to get data to compute the advantage in actor-critic settings.

I know that `A(s,a) = Q(s,a) - V(s)`. It seems straightforward to get the state value estimate `V(s)`, but how can we estimate `Q(s,a)` given that the policy only outputs probabilities?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Q function depends on the availability of reward values for each future state.  Q(s, a) is the value of taking action `a` and evaluating the resulting `V(s')` for the new state `s'`.  Thus, the net advantage will be the sum across all actions `a` of `P(a) * V(s'(a))`, where `s'(a)` is the state reached by taking action `a` from stat `s`.

Remember, this is only a value *estimate*; that's where the training iterations prove their worth.  You keep iterating until the values converge to a stable Markov model.

Answer (score 0):

You should estimate **Q(s,a)** using the **critic**, not the **actor**.

Remember that in the **actor-critic** setting (e.g. A2C), the actor(s) will **output** the probability distribution over all your actions at state `s`. From this distribution, you'll sample an action `a` to take in the environment. Then, the environment will give you a reward `r` and the next state `s'`.

After `N` steps, you'll use the **critic** to estimate the **state value** `V(s)` and will calculate the **advantage** to point out how much better your actions were than the average for example. With the advantage, you'll update your policy (**actor**) to increase/decrease the probability of taking the action `a` at state `s`.

Therefore, to use your **advantage function** in this framework, you could use the critic to estimate `Q(s,a)`, which is the value for each pair of action-state. Then, you can estimate `V(s)` with:

[image]

You can take a look at this [answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/31791) and at this [post](https://danieltakeshi.github.io/2017/04/02/notes-on-the-generalized-advantage-estimation-paper/) to have a better idea. Note that, to estimate `Q(s,a)` your critic network should have `|A|` output units, instead of just one as in the case of `V(s)`. There are also other options to try as your advantage function.

Remember that the only purpose of the advantage function is to tell your model how much to increase/decrease the probabilities of taking action `a` at state `s`. If it's better than average you increase otherwise you decrease.

This [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02438.pdf) is a very good reference.